# .htaccess not redirecting all requests to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following set as my .htaccess file for develop.metrolansing.com:

```
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /forum https://develop.metrolansing.com/discussions
RedirectMatch ^/$ /discussions/
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2016/09/(.*)$ /ebay/$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

Requests to http://develop.metrolansing.com are redirected to https://develop.metrolansing.com, and also requests to http://develop.metrolansing.com/forum are redirected to https://develop.metrolansing.com/discussions (the site now lives at /discussions).

However, if I visit http://develop.metrolansing.com/discussions, the request isn't redirected to https.

Why isn't the last line redirecting the request for the subdirectory properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that `/discussions` is a physical directory that has it's own `.htaccess` file in which you are using mod_rewrite (to handle your *forum*)? mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default, so mod_rewrite directives in the `/discussions/.htaccess` file will completely override the parent directives and your HTTP to HTTPS redirect will not happen.

You could perhaps enable mod_rewrite inheritance by including the following towards the top of the subdirectory's `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

However, it would be preferable to incorporate the directives from the subdirectory's `.htaccess` file in the parent `.htaccess` file (making any adjustments where necessary).

You should also avoid mixing mod_alias (`Redirect` and `RedirectMatch`) redirect directives with mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) redirects. Different modules are processed at different times during the request, so the outcome can be confusing and you can end up with unexpected conflicts. mod_rewrite generally executes first, despite the apparent order in `.htaccess`.